# Simultaneous measurement using mutually unbiased bases (MUB)

Tags: measurement, mub

I have some questions about the paper “O(N^3) Measurement Cost for Variational
Quantum Eigensolver on Molecular Hamiltonians”.

About the section 8 of this paper, they mentioned that the measurement of [XX, ZZ] can be transferred to [ZI, IZ] by unitary conjugation. So how to classically reconstruct the result of [XX, ZZ] by [ZI, IZ]?

The paper also mentioned that (4^N-1) Pauli strings can be divided into (2^N+1) commuting family and each commuting family only needs one measurement. I wonder what the process to reconstruct the result for each commuting family?
Thanks for answering!!!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What does "process to reconstruct the result for each commuting family" mean? Are you asking how to reconstruct the expectation value of $\langle XX\rangle$ and $\langle ZZ\rangle$ by measuring $\langle ZI\rangle$ and $\langle IZ\rangle$?

Comment: Yes. Can we get the result of ⟨ZI⟩ by the computation of ⟨IZ⟩ and ⟨ZZ⟩?

Comment: you say yes, but now you seem to be asking a different question.. so which is it?

Comment: Sorry. Because in the paper they mentioned that the expectation value of ⟨XX⟩ and ⟨ZZ⟩ can be reconstructed by the Bell state measurement of ⟨ZI⟩ and ⟨IZ⟩. So my first question is how to reconstruct the expectation value of ⟨XX⟩ and ⟨ZZ⟩ by measuring ⟨ZI⟩ and ⟨IZ⟩. Besides, if ⟨ZI⟩ and ⟨IZ⟩ still needs two circuits to measure them seperately, there is no advantage of replace ⟨XX⟩, ⟨ZZ⟩ by ⟨ZI⟩, ⟨IZ⟩. So I wonder how to get the result of ⟨ZI⟩ by the computation of ⟨IZ⟩ and ⟨ZZ⟩ so only one circuit is needed. Thanks for answering!!!

Comment: you cannot recover eg $\langle ZZ\rangle$ from $\langle ZI\rangle$ and $\langle IZ\rangle$ alone. As a counterexample, consider $|01\rangle+|10\rangle$ and $|00\rangle+|11\rangle$